# use cordova cli to generate xcarchive file

Tags: ios, cordova, xcarchive

I use `cordova -- build ios --device` to successfully generated signed *.ipa file, however it seems there is no *.xcarchive file here:

`2018-10-18T21:02:53.4124540Z ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
2018-10-18T21:02:53.4125690Z 
2018-10-18T21:02:53.7699240Z 2018-10-18 16:02:53.769 xcodebuild[24727:142486] 
2018-10-18T21:02:53.9046040Z 2018-10-18 16:02:53.904 xcodebuild[24727:142486] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/jr/j1yxcy8x1zqb9pkr64dwp0mw0000gn/T/App_2018-10-18_16-02-53.903.xcdistributionlogs'.
2018-10-18T21:03:01.5280840Z Exported App.xcarchive to: /Users/alekseimelezhik/agent01/_work/2/s/platforms/ios/build/device
2018-10-18T21:03:01.5281720Z ** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **`

In my case I have only `platforms/ios/build/device/App.ipa` file, and cannot fine `App.xcarchive` ( it seems it gets removed after export ?)

The question is, how to make `cordova build` to generate ( keep ) *.xcarchive file as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is there `App.xcarchive` under `platforms/ios` directory?